# Link duplicate radio button forms

Tags: javascript, html

So, I want to display a set of radio buttons several places on a page. I want the state of the radio buttons to be linked, select option A on one form should select option A in all forms.

Sorry for not including examples.

Here is the idea:

```
<form id="serverForm">
   <input type="radio" name="@(site.SiteID)" class="serverRadio" value="All"> All
   <input type="radio" name="@(site.SiteID)" class="serverRadio" value="DS1"> DS1
   <input type="radio" name="@(site.SiteID)" class="serverRadio" value="DS2"> DS2
   <input type="radio" name="@(site.SiteID)" class="serverRadio" value="IS1"> IS1
</form>
```

This form is going to be created multiple times dynamically depending on the size of the loops its contained in. I want each of these forms to essentially act as duplicated. Clicking an option on one will update all.

Comment: So that's what you want? Can we see what you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. Give a class attribute to all Radiobuttons.
2. Add an "on Click" event on that class.
3. Check the clicked radio button's value in the event
4. Compare the value with other radio buttons (in a loop for all radio buttons), if it's the same put the attribute "checked" on true

P.S.: Share your code next time so an easy code example can be provided or even the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.)Make all the position 1 buttons of forms to same div and position 2 buttons to other same div and so on.
2.)Use any technique(like directing to any function or adding an onClick event in jquery) to check the changed class like:-

```
$(".class_to_be_checked").attr("checked","checked");
```